# JBoss Fuse Hibernate integration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jbossfuse

I try to develop simple Hibernate integration application in FUSE but could not find good reference document which I can follow. I have go through the [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/EIP_Transaction_Guide/files/TxnManagers-Samples-Hibernate.html) regarding Hibernate integration but could not able to install the dependencies correctly.

I noticed that hibernate should configured in camel-context file but unfortunately when I add this kind of configuration I'm getting following error. When I try to install my app in to Fuse.

[image]

```
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to start bundle mvn:com.activemq.cxf/activemq/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle DemoActiveMq1 [416]: Unable to resolve 416.0: missing requirement [416.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 415.0: missing requirement [415.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.dao)(version>=3.0.5)(!(version>=3.0.6)))]
```

But I check there is no version 3.0.5 available for org.springframework.dao. According to the [this post](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao) it's only available 2.0.8 . Please can some one explain how to resolve this issue ?

Following are the dependencies related to Hibernate in my pom(${spring-version}== 3.0.5.RELEASE)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Fuse myself and may be there is something special about it. However there is a common misunderstanding regrading how OSGi works in your question. The `org.springframework.dao` it is complaining about is not an artifact but java package. That package can be provided by any artifact. Little googling reveals that since version 2.5.x the package is moved to [`spring-tx`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx) artifact. My guess is, adding that to your dependencies and / or deploying it in your OSGi enviroment should fix the problem. Since Fuse is using Karaf you probably can use Karaf's features to install in.